# Autenticação com nó js e passaportes usando GCF

Tags: node.js, google, cloud

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de autenticar requisesoes das funções da nuvem no google usando o nodejs e o passaporte, sempre que eu quiser saber o que é necessário para verificar se eu estou autenticado e retornar à solicitação

Comment: O idioma aqui é Português, traduza a pergunta.

Comment: [Veja este link para ajudar a melhorar a sua pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/26504)